# Looping through DynamoDB Items Properties

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a DynamoDB Table with several different types of records with different properties. I am trying to figure out how I can run a forEach loop through each item record and check each property value without checking the property ahead of time.

Pseudocode:

1. Scan the Table
2. Run forEach on the data.Items
3. Run forEach on each data.Items Property's
4. Check if property.value == null

I wrote something similiar to what I am trying to do in C# but I would need to do this in Javascript.

```
 try
                    {
                        foreach (var currentItem in items)
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> tempitem = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>();
                            bool nullFound = false;
                            foreach (var property in currentItem)  // Check each property attribute (dynamodb column associated with current record)
                            {
                                if (property.Value.NULL)   // Only true if the property field was assigned the value of NULL = true
                                {
                                    nullFound = true;
                                    UpdateNullFieldsToEmpty(currentItem["PK"].S, currentItem["SK"].S, property.Key); // Update Item Record in DynamoDB Table


                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    tempitem.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
                                }
                            }
```

Using something like this...

```
data.Items.forEach(function (Item) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem doing the following:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    await ReadMessage().then(data => {
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            for (var attributename in item) {
                if (item[attributename] === null) {
                    UpdateNullFieldsToEmpty(item.PK, item.SK, attributename);
                }
            }
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
};
```